# npm install from local packages only

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm familiar with Python's package manager `pip`. Pip has an option to specify "[never make any network calls](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-from-local-packages), all packages and dependencies should be fetched from a local directory".

Is something similar possible with npm?

I want a lighter weight build process, and want all the node packages to be installed from a local folder with .tgz files or similar.

Answer (score 1):

If the folder in question will be used as a package repository of sorts, I  think [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) should do the job

```
cd ~/<local-packages-dir>/<pkg>
npm link

cd ~/<project-dir>
npm link <pkg> // installs package to ~/<project-dir>/node_modules/<pkg>
```

Any changes to made to `~/<local-packages-dir>/<pkg>` after being linked will be reflected in `~/<project-dir>/node_modules/<pkg>`.

---

Also to note, `npm install` will install a tarball or a folder directly

> `npm install <folder>:`
>
> Install a package that is sitting in a folder on the filesystem.
>
> `npm install <tarball file>:`
>
> Install a package that is sitting on the filesystem. Note: if you just want to link a dev directory into your npm root, you can do this more easily by using `npm link`.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
>      npm install ./package.tgz
> ```

Comment: OK I see. How does ``npm install folder/tarball`` handle dependencies?

Comment: @codeape what do you mean by handle dependencies? It should treat them just like other NPM packages, it will attempt to install them at the top level, unless there is a conflict with a dependency in your `package.json` then it will install that dependency nested within the dependent packages folder in `node_modules`.

Comment: What I mean is: Will ``npm install folder/tarball`` attempt to download dependencies from the internet?